# ¿Como eliminar una lista, dependiendo de los elementos dentro de dicha lista? Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, lista

El caso es que quiero obtener una lista con todos las combinaciones posibles de los números del 1 al 12. Excluyendo las combinaciones con los mimos números. Un ejemplo:

```
[1,2,3] #Se añade a la lista
[2,3,1] #No se añade a la lista, por que ya se había añadido una con los mismos elementos
```

Empecé generando la lista con todos las combinaciones posibles (con las repetidas) (12 * 12 * 12). Adjunto el código:

```
for i in range(len("000000000000")):
    for j in range(len("000000000000")):
        for k in range(len("000000000000")):
            arr.append([i + 1,j + 1,k + 1])
```

Cuando imprimo por pantalla,

```
print(len(arr))
```

me da el resultado que deseo:

```
1728
```

Luego decidí eliminar de las lista en cuestión los elementos que tienen los mismo 3 números, como `[1,1,1]`:

```
for a in range(len(arr)):
    if arr[a][0] ==  arr[a][1] and arr[a][0] == arr[a][2]:
        del arr[a]
```

**Ahí es donde surge el error**, itero sobre todas las combinaciones y comparo si los tres elementos son iguales, dependiendo de eso elimino dicha combinación. Ejecutando esto me topo con el el siguiente error:

```
  File "C:\Users\gabriel\Desktop\conjuntos.py", line 12, in <module>
    if arr[a][0] ==  arr[a][1] and arr[a][0] == arr[a][2]:
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Por lo que entiendo, este error se genera cuando se intenta acceder a un elemento que no está en la lista. Esto no tiene sentido ya que las combinaciones tienen tres elementos (índices 0,1,2):

```
print(len(arr[0]))
print(arr[0])

3
[1, 1, 1]
```

El ciclo `for` itera sobre el rango de la longitud de `arr`, del 0 al 1727. En teoría debería ser capaz de acceder a los elementos.

No sé como solucionar este problema, ya que todos los recursos en internet dice algo como "cundo intentas acceder al indice 52 cuando hay hasta el 52". Ocupo solucionar esto, mi plan era luego aplicar comparacón de conjuntos para eliminar todas las combinaciones repetidas, algo así:

```
for x in range(len(arr)):
    out = arr[x]

    for y in range(len(arr)):
        if len(set(out) & set(arr[y])) < 3:
            del arr[y]
            aux.append(out)
```

**Nota:** Borro el array sobre el que itera con `del arr[y]`para que no lo tome en cuenta en el siguiente ciclo.

Resumiendo mi pregunta, **¿Por qué se genera este error cuando se puede acceder a todos los elementos, como puedo realizar esa comparación y eliminar el array que contiene los elementos sobre los que estoy iterando?** Cualquier corrección o respuesta la agradecería. Muchas gracias de antemano, y un saludo. Adjunto el código entero (es muy corto)

```
arr = []
aux = []

for i in range(len("000000000000")):
    for j in range(len("000000000000")):
        for k in range(len("000000000000")):
            arr.append([i + 1,j + 1,k + 1])

for a in range(len(arr)):
    if arr[a][0] ==  arr[a][1] and arr[a][0] == arr[a][2]:
        del arr[a]

for x in range(len(arr)):
    out = arr[x]

    for y in range(len(arr)):
        if len(set(out) & set(arr[y])) < 3:
            del arr[y]
            aux.append(out)

print(len(arr))
print(len(aux))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### El problema

No debes eliminar elementos de un array mientras iteras por él. Eso cambia la longitud del array y como consecuencia no sólo podrás encontrar errores como el que te ha sucedido, sino que también cambia lo que esperas en `elemento[i]` si has eliminado algún elemento anterior a `[i]`.

Para eliminar elementos de un array deberías trabajar con una copia. Recorres la copia y eliminas en cambio del original.

Otra posibilidad es, en lugar de eliminar, añadir a un auxiliar. Comienzas con un array auxiliar vacío y vas recorriendo tu array original y añadiendo al auxiliar todos los elementos del original que desees conservar, dejando sin añadir los que no.

### Una solución mejor

En tu caso particular, no necesitas crear primero un array con todos para luego pasar sólo algunos al resultado, sino que directamente, según vas creando la lista, puedes añadir sólo aquellos que cumplan tu condición, saltándote los que no.

Por ejemplo, se puede hacer un conjunto con los elementos (i,j,k) y mirar la longitud de ese conjunto. Si es menor de 3, es que tiene elementos repetidos y en ese caso nos lo saltamos:

```
arr =[]

for i in range(12):
    for j in range(12):
        for k in range(12):
            if len(set([i,j,k]))<3:
                continue
            arr.append(frozenset([i,j,k]))

print(len(arr))
```

El resultado tiene 1320 elementos que si no entendí mal serían los que buscabas.

## Edición

Releyendo tu pregunta, veo que mi anterior solución aún producirá elementos que no quieres tener, pues por ejemplo el [1,2,3] y el [2,1,3] ambos serían añadidos al no contener elementos repetidos, pero parece que lo que querrías es tener sólo uno de ellos.

Creo que entonces la mejor solución para este caso es no "reinventar la rueda" y hacer uso de las utilidades que te vienen en la biblioteca estándar. En concreto, el módulo `itertools` trae una función `combinations()` que parece hacer exactamente lo que necesitas:

```
import itertools
arr = list(itertools.combinations(range(12), 3))
print(len(arr))
```

Ahora salen solo 220 combinaciones, que comenzarían así:

```
(0, 1, 2)
(0, 1, 3)
(0, 1, 4)
(0, 1, 5)
(0, 1, 6)
(0, 1, 7)
(0, 1, 8)
(0, 1, 9)
(0, 1, 10)
(0, 1, 11)
(0, 2, 3)
(0, 2, 4)
(0, 2, 5)
(0, 2, 6)
(0, 2, 7)
(0, 2, 8)
(0, 2, 9)
(0, 2, 10)
(0, 2, 11)
(0, 3, 4)
(0, 3, 5)
(0, 3, 6)
...
```

Como ves, la `(0,0,0)` que sería la primera, no está en el resultado por tener ceros repetidos. Entre las que comienzan por `(0,1,...)` salen todas excepto `(0,1,0)` y `(0,1,1)`, por contener cifras repetidas. En las que comienzan por `(0,2,...)` ya no aparece la `(0,2,0)` ni la `(0,2,2)`, por tener cifras repetidas, pero tampoco aparece la `(0,2,1)` porque ya salió antes la `(0,1,2)`, etc.

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu respuesta, pero creo que no te quedó claro mi objetivo. Yo quería eliminar las combinaciones con tres cifras iguales, con el fin de luego aplicar uso del operador `&`. Si no eliminaba las combinaciones con tres cifras iguales iba obtener un set como {0}. De todos modos, tu respuesta me es muy útil. Saludos y muchas gracias.